# how to improve the result of tesseract when the words has background image

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I am trying to extract numbers from images. I test tesseract-OCR, but the result is not good enough. For example,

```
tesseract test.jpg stdout --psm 6
```

[image]

will output:

```
4367 42424W0 104
```

I assume the issue is due to there is some background images in the back of the words. Is there any way that can improve the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the `convert` command of `ImageMagick` to threshold the image to back-in-white. You can download `ImageMagick` [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php), it supports multiple platform.

By typing,

```
convert image.jpg -threshold 33% thresholded.jpg
```

It outputs the image below. The threshold value is obtained after few attempts and adjustments.

[image]

Then, with the basic `tesseract` command it gives a correct output.

[image]

If the image only consists of 0-9, you may enable the tesseract option to improve the recognition accuracy - `-c tessedit_char_whitelist=01234567890"`.

Hope this help.